# Integrate dy=arctan(f(x)*dx)?

Tags: integration

I came across an odd geometry problem where I can straightforwardly identify the relation:

$$ d\theta=\tan^{-1}(f(x)dx) $$

I would like to find an equation for y(x) but I don't know how to get dx out of the trig function. I think the solution is to separate the right hand side to the form

$$ d\theta=g(f(x))dx $$

but I'm not sure how to do that. I've tried looking for ways to decompose arctans but I haven't found anything that gets me where I'm trying to go. How can I find y(x)?

**Context**

For context, per comment request, see the following figure:
[image]

I know the function $\beta(t)$, the angle between the blue curve and the radial line going through it at that point defined parametrically with $t$, and I want to know the function $\theta(t)$, the angle between the blue line and the x axis.

So I figured $d\theta$ was the artan of the incremental path length of the blue line times $sin(\beta)$ divided by the radial distance between the origin and the blue line (along the green line). Or, $d\theta=tan^{-1}(sin(beta)dm/R)$.

**Solution?**

I think the solution here may be to use the small angle approximation. Since $dm<<R$, I can approximate $tan^{-1}(f(x)dx)=f(x)dx$. Then, its a simple integration.

Comment: Try Taylor formula for arctan. $dy = \arctan(f(x)dx) = f(x)dx+o(dx)$

Comment: Why is the differential inside the trig function in the first place? That's highly unusual. Can you please provide more higher-level context?

Comment: It would be helpful if you add the source for the problem.

Comment: It would make more sense ir it was $dy=\arctan(f(x))\,dx.$ No idea what this notation means.